# upgrade completed IOS 4.3 iphone app for Ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a fully functional Iphone app optimized for IOS 4.x (no storyboards). I need to upgrade it to work on both the iphone and ipad. My main question is whether to one, change the devices value in the app summary to universal. Or two, duplicate the target, leave the iphone app as is, and make the necessary changes to the ipad version.

From what I have been reading, after changing the app summary to universal, new files will be added for the ipad version. This is not happening. Can anyone suggest the best approach for upgrading an older app?

Comment: Another note. I duplicated the target for ipad that resulted in the .xib files being copied over and set for ipad. I edited the scheme to build the Ipad target. The ipad app builds fine but breaks right after the app is launched. Are there any manual changes I need to make to the code?  Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to reset my iOS Device. Did this by opening the iOS simulator and going to iOS Simulator-> Reset Content and Settings..